# Register setting on plugin activation

Tags: plugins, php, options

I want to register an option when my plugin is activated to be used in the settings page.

My first attempt:

```
function jpsNews_activate_plugin() {
    // REGISTER SETTINGS
    register_setting( 'jps_settings_group', 'jps_test');
    ...
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'jpsNews_activate_plugin');
```

Second attempt:

```
function jpsNews_activate_plugin() {
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'jps_settings' );
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'jpsNews_activate_plugin');

function jps_settings() {
    // REGISTER SETTINGS
    register_setting( 'jps_settings_group', 'jps_test');
}
```

When i go to the database and search for that option, nothing is found. What am i missing? Can i do it like this?

Thanks in advance.

Update:

This is how i did the settings page:

```
function jps_mail_list_page_entry() {
add_menu_page(
    __('JPS Mailing List'),
    'JPS Mailing List',
    'manage_options',
    'jpsNews_mailinglist',
    'jpsNews_mailing_list',
    'dashicons-email'
);
add_submenu_page('jpsNews_mailinglist', 'Settings', 'Settings', 'manage_options', 
 'mailinglist-settings', 'snaq_mailing_settings');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'jps_mail_list_page_entry');
```

Comment: Hi. I'm confused about what you are trying to do.  This should be hooked into `admin-init` as far as I know, not plugin activation.

Comment: this is the first time im seeing this so im a litle confused also. Im trying to add an options page to my plugin and save those options in the database. As i said, i dont even know if its possible to do it on plugin activation.

Comment: Well your question is actually two questions. 1) How to add an option page 2) How to save some defaults values on activation. Right?

Comment: I know how to add a page. I already have a page for the settings (empty for now). I just cant create the options i want to use in that page.

Comment: That depends on how you create the page, and how your sanitation works. Is it possible to add your full code to the question? I think you need to work with the `get_option()`.

Comment: posted how i did the page under update. now, all i need is to create the options

Comment: Creating a plugin option page and saving/sanitizing the options takes more than that. [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/271669/94498) is my answer about a fully working option page. See if you can get it to work.

Comment: tks, i'll give it a try