# How can I get my options in json response?

Tags: theme-options, json

I have made a function to download a JSON file with all the options in WordPress and my own options that I have made in my theme options page and it works fine.

**Here is the code:**

```
$options = get_alloptions(); // Get all options data, return array

    foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
        $value = maybe_unserialize($value);
        $need_options[$key] = $value;
    }

$json_file = json_encode($need_options);
```

**So what's the problem:**

The problem is in the downloaded file there are too many options I want to limit them means I want only the options that are made by me in my theme options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't save your theme's options one by one. In that case, you should call each of them separately, or store them in an array and then run a loop to get their values:

```
$options = array( 'option1', 'option2', 'option3');
foreach( $options as $option ){
    // The rest of your code
}
```

But the proper way would always be to serialize and store all of your theme's options in a single option. Take a look at [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/271669/94498) answer of mine, which you can find the functions to do this in the code.

Another approach would be to use a unique prefix for your options. For example, use `something-` as a prefix, and then check the retrieved option for that string:

```
$options = get_alloptions(); // Get all options data, return array

    foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
        if( stristr( $key, 'something-' ) )  {
            $value = maybe_unserialize($value);
            $need_options[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

$json_file = json_encode($need_options);
```

Comment: save my theme's options one by one sorry I can't understand what do you mean

Comment: I mean, instead of storing EACH option in a separate database row, serialize all of your theme's options and save them in a single database row.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do that because I have made my options without using Setting API ;) so is still possible to make all the options in one row.

Comment: The linked answer includes a full working example of plugin setting page (It's the same as theme, just have to change it to `add_theme_page`). Also I have updated the answer.